# Mysqldump/MySql avoid overwriting testers database development

Tags: mysql, backup

So I'm working on this bash script, which has to create a backup of both the `production database and work environment database`, this is easy enough and done like this:

```sh
bin/mysqldump.exe -uUsername -p-hHost.com --lock-tables=false --single-transaction --routines --triggers production_database >backups/dump_production_database .sql

bin/mysqldump.exe -uUsername -p-hHost.com --lock-tables=false --single-transaction --routines --triggers testers_database >backups/dump_testers_database .sql
```

BUT the `testers_database` is at the moment updated manually, and I want it to be updated automatic.

Then I though, lets just use `MySql.exe` like this, to update the `testers_database`:

```sh
bin/mysql.exe -uUsername -p -hHost.com testers_database <backups/dump_production_database .sql
```

BUT then I thought of a problem here.. `What if the developers have added new columns to tables, edits to existing functions or something like that, then this would be overwritten?` How should I create this `mysql.exe` command, so it's not overwriting anything valuable to the developers? Can I somehow do a validation check, that checks if there is any new edits to functions/new columns to existing tables etc., then don't drop that table and create the old / just skip this command? Or should I just forget about this `automatic update`, and have the developers update the database themselves and wait `30min for it to complete the database update?`

Right now when they develop they test that it's working on the `testers_database` and if everything is working there it's implemented it to the `production_database` manually which is fine, but I dont want this bash script to ruin their progress/changes to their test_database only to keep their database updated with the newest results all the time, so they don't have to do it themselves.

Comment: Why would you automatically update the tester's database if there is no issue with the database? You usually restore backups in case there is something wrong with the database.

Comment: Mostly it's because it's anoying for the developers to copy the production database to their test_database, if they need the latests results on their test playground. But I might just create the script without the `mysql` part and then just have them update it manually when they need new results on their playground. Then they are in control themselves on when to test changes on their test environment.

Comment: It is unlikely that a developer wants to copy the entire prod database into test / dev environment as such a move would overwrite any changes done to the structure. You need to enable the developers to be able to transfer custom production datasets into tables in the dev environment on demand. I would probably have a mirror database of the production database that devs can use to pull data on demand from.

Comment: Make a script that creates a backup of the devs database and prods database. Then I've also made a .cmd script the devs can run (telling them what will be affected by running this .cmd script), and if they click [Y] yes, the test_database will be a replica of the prods_database. This script will only make existing tables/function/stored_procedures, as in the prods_database. New tables etc. will be kept in the devs database. Then they have a easy way to update the database @Shadow

Comment: Note: they have access to manually do all this if they want. but this is just an easier way to make sure it is as it should be, and also without having to edit .sql files 5GB+.